# qemu-system-x86_64 vs qemu-system-sh4 vs qemu-system-i386 which is better?

Tags: qemu

What is the difference with 3 types of qemu? I can run each of them and it looks the same to me..
qemu-system-x86_64 and qemu-system-i386 are version 3.0.0
qemu-system-sh4 is version 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different.
`qemu-system-x86_64` emulated x86 64 bit architecture.
`qemu-system-i386` emulated x86 32 bit architecture. 
`qemu-system-sh4` emulated SuperH (SH) architecutre.

For each type of architecture, there are corresponding virtual board can be specified.